# Show data from timestamp by week

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I am trying to select data from mysql table and sort it per week by class_id.
my table structur:

```
=======================================
id + class_id + student_id + timestamp
=======================================
1  + 1        +  2         + 12/09/2014 13:00:01
2  + 1        +  3         + 12/09/2014 13:00:10
3  + 2        +  2         + 12/09/2014 15:01:01
4  + 2        +  3         + 12/09/2014 15:04:01
5  + 1        +  2         + 19/09/2014 13:00:40
6  + 1        +  3         + 19/09/2014 13:01:01
```

My questions are:
1. How to show the total weeks by class_id. Example: for class_id:1 there are 2 weeks. week 1 = 12/09, week 2 =19/09.
2. How to show student_id that attandance at week selected. Example want to see student attandance at week 2.

Thanks before :)

Comment: since your dates are probably being stored as text/varchar, you'll have a lot of work ahead of you to be able to use mysql's built-in date/time functions.

Answer (score 0):

1) 
SELECT
    class_id
    , count(*)
FROM [your_table]
group by class_id

2)
SELECT
    id
    , student_id
FROM [your_table]
WHERE id = 2

Check REF @
http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-group-by.aspx